# Listen to global mouse event from React component

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I would like to have a component that sets the content of it's `<div>` based on a data attribute of a different component the mouse is hovering over. For example, I would like the `data-message` attribute of this component:

```
<ComponentA data-message="This is a message" />
```

To set the state of `ComponentB` when the mouse enters `ComponentA`:

```
class ComponentB extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div>this.state.message</div>
        );
    }
}
```

There will possibly be 1000's of components with this data attribute.

**How can I have a single mouse event listener which listens to any component with a certain data attribute?**

Comment: One approach would be to create a HOC which enhances a container component to listen to mouse events. It can be given a filter to process only those events which are sourced from the divs which have the message attribute. The next step will be to have the captured data flow through the component tree down to the component where you display it. This can be done through Context, or more preferably using a store.

Comment: Here's a quick mouse event spy SOC implementation - https://jsfiddle.net/HaZardous/1x2mtLwc/